# How to loop through two arrays and find common value object? Javascript using forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to looping thought two arrays and find where is value expanded = true set to first array?

example of first array:

```
[ 
 { id: 1 , name: 'Test 1' , expended = false },
 { id: 2 , name: 'Test 2' , expended = false },
 { id: 3 , name: 'Test 3' , expended = false }
]
```

exaple of second array:

```
[ 
 { id: 1 , name: 'Test 1' , expended = false },
 { id: 2 , name: 'Test 2' , expended = true },
 { id: 3 , name: 'Test 3' , expended = false }
]
```

Different between two array is only expended value where is on second array is :

```
 { id: 2 , name: 'Test 2' , expended = true }
```

I need to loop thought first array and second and find in second array where is expended = true and just paste on first array.

The expected result above after the loop should be:

***first array value***

```
[ 
 { id: 1 , name: 'Test 1' , expended = false },
 { id: 2 , name: 'Test 2' , expended = true },
 { id: 3 , name: 'Test 3' , expended = false }
]
```

Please, I can't just copy the value of all array!

this example is not accepted:

this.secondArray = this.firstArray..

This is a simple example I sent you. I have 10 more parameters in the object that are changing, but it is only important for me to be expended to copy!

Literally, the value expended from the second array to copy to the first and that's it!

Comment: this.secondArray = this.firstArray.. wouldn't work anyway and this question is not a pleasant reading experience I feel like i'm being asked a question on an exam...

Comment: so, why yo don't use something line for loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update one array with data from another array using Key of Id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567914/how-to-update-one-array-with-data-from-another-array-in-javascript-using-key-of) also [How can I update an array based on another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46591628/how-can-i-update-an-array-based-on-another-array-on-matching-index) and [Update the first array object  based on the second array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59739021/update-the-first-array-object-value-based-on-the-second-array-by-comparing-a-fie)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the result using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

You can set the value of `expended` if value of `expended` of `arr1` is false as

```
arr1.map((o) => ({ ...o, expended: o.expended || map.get(o.id).expended }))
```

```js
const arr1 = [
  { id: 1, name: "Test 1", expended: false },
  { id: 2, name: "Test 2", expended: false },
  { id: 3, name: "Test 3", expended: false },
];

const arr2 = [
  { id: 1, name: "Test 1", expended: false },
  { id: 2, name: "Test 2", expended: true },
  { id: 3, name: "Test 3", expended: false },
];

const map = new Map(arr2.map((o) => [o.id, o]));

const result = arr1.map((o) => ({ ...o, expended: o.expended || map.get(o.id).expended }));
console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you want the result with forEach

```js
const arr1 = [
  { id: 1, name: "Test 1", expended: false },
  { id: 2, name: "Test 2", expended: false },
  { id: 3, name: "Test 3", expended: false },
];

const arr2 = [
  { id: 1, name: "Test 1", expended: false },
  { id: 2, name: "Test 2", expended: true },
  { id: 3, name: "Test 3", expended: false },
];

arr1.forEach((obj) => {
  const elementInArr2 = arr2.find((o) => o.id === obj.id);
  if (elementInArr2) obj.expended = obj.expended || elementInArr2.expended;
});

console.log(arr1);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I need forEach friend..i need forEach... I'm using angular 9 and new Subject ... I can't do that. I intentionally wrote forEach

Comment: @yajoj98337 code udpated with forEach also. This is even more simple than with Map

Answer (score 0):

- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), iterate over the second array while updating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), if the object's `expended` is `true`, set the key to the `id` and the value to the object
- Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), iterate over the first array. For every object check if the above map has its `id` and replace it, otherwise keep it

```js
let 
  arr1 = [ { id: 1, name: 'Test 1', expended: false }, { id: 2, name: 'Test 2', expended: false }, { id: 3, name: 'Test 3', expended: false } ],
  arr2 = [ { id: 1, name: 'Test 1', expended: false }, { id: 2, name: 'Test 2', expended: true }, { id: 3, name: 'Test 3', expended: false } ];
  
const expenededMap = arr2.reduce((map, obj) => {
  if(obj.expended) map.set(obj.id, obj);
  return map;
}, new Map);

arr1 = arr1.map(obj => {
  if(obj.expended) return obj;
  const objFromArr2 = expenededMap.get(obj.id) || {};
  return objFromArr2.expended ? objFromArr2 : obj;
});

console.log(arr1);
```

Using just [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
let 
  arr1 = [ { id: 1, name: 'Test 1', expended: false }, { id: 2, name: 'Test 2', expended: false }, { id: 3, name: 'Test 3', expended: false } ],
  arr2 = [ { id: 1, name: 'Test 1', expended: false }, { id: 2, name: 'Test 2', expended: true }, { id: 3, name: 'Test 3', expended: false } ];
  
arr1.forEach((obj, i, arr) => {
  if(!obj.expended) {
    const objFromArr2 = arr2.find(({ id }) => id === obj.id) || {};
    if(objFromArr2.expended) arr[i] = objFromArr2;
  }
});

console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: I need forEach friend..i need forEach... I'm using angular 9 and new Subject ... I can't do that. I intentionally wrote forEach

Comment: @yajoj98337 you can only use forEach? can you use find with it for example?